# MLUpdateContext is empty when updating CoreML model

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

My problem is the following - In the method below the variable `finalContext` seem to not contain anything. I get error message : `Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)` when calling the function. I need help how to debug this issue or what could be the possible cause for this. EDIT - `finalContext` does not contain the model that I am trying to access.

```
func updateModel(){
    //Configuration for when update is performed
    let modelConfig = MLModelConfiguration()
    modelConfig.computeUnits = .cpuAndGPU
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    //Image batch for updating the model
    //Might need to change from a batch to a single image
    let updateImages: [UIImage] = [theImage!]
    let imageBatch = createTrainingData(imageArray: updateImages, outputLabel: "dog") // temp outputLabel
    do {
        let updateTask = try MLUpdateTask(forModelAt: globalCompiledModel!, trainingData: imageBatch, configuration: modelConfig,
                         progressHandlers: MLUpdateProgressHandlers(forEvents: [.trainingBegin,.epochEnd],
                          progressHandler: { (contextProgress) in
                            print(contextProgress.event)
                            // you can check the progress here, after each epoch
                         }) { (finalContext) in
                                do {
                                    // Save the updated model to temporary filename.
                                    let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true)
                                    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("CatDog.mlmodelc")
                                    print("Updated temp model URL: \(fileURL)")
                                    try finalContext.model.write(to: fileURL)
                                } catch(let error) {
                                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
        })
        updateTask.resume()
    } catch {
        print("Error while updating: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: After some debugging here is also contents of ```finalContext``` :
po finalContext
```task: 0x6000001c0ba0, 
model: 0x0, 
event: (
    "Training End"
), 
metrics: {
}, 
parameters: {
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue here. MLArrayBatchProvider was not properly configured by me so the updateTask was not properly completed.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful with the particular configuration that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Es domaj, ka vajag panemt iepist al un paprovet velreiz

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. please write your answer in English language as Latvian is not an international language. and if you dont write code in your answer, please comment on the question instead

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was resolved by abandoning using a UpdatableTrainingInput class that conformed to id<MLFeatureProvider>, but instead creating a MLDictionaryFeatureProvider as shown here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/model_personalization/personalizing_a_model_with_on-device_updates?language=objc